Deputy Undermining My Onboarding – Tips for Handling the Situation?
I recently started a new position as project lead. In the team, there’s a colleague who has been here for a year, covering part of the responsibilities for some projects and officially acting as my deputy. As far as I know, she didn’t apply for my role (the salary difference is minimal). Moving forward, we’ll have to work closely together.
She’s currently in charge of my onboarding, but her constant comments are really getting on my nerves, like: “Am I missing something? Not that you could judge…” or “Anyone could do your job.” She’s even taken a few of my ideas in meetings and presented them as her own.
I’m naturally a quiet person, while she’s very outspoken, which doesn’t make the situation any easier. My boss seems to get along well with her. She even went to our boss to complain that my predecessor didn’t involve her as an equal, which is completely exaggerated since she learned almost everything from her. I believe she might be dealing with some insecurities or issues. Generally, she runs to the boss quite often.
What makes this especially frustrating is that I’ve actually gone out of my way to be extra kind to her. I even downplayed my new role, pretending it wasn’t anything special, just to avoid hurting her ego
How would you handle this?

Is there a question in there somewhere?

Too much context missing here to give you good advice, even if you did have a specific question (which you don't). How long of a time period is "recently"? Is this person your direct report, your equal, etc? is any part of your job actually harder because of her?

To solicit a good answer here you need to give a lot more info. Also, "how would you handle this" isn't really on topic here. Please rephrase to be more specific about what your problem is and which steps to deal with it you need help with.

Have you told her that this bothers you and you'd appreciate it if she stopped? She may not even realize she's doing it.

To echo InBedded16s comment (which is critical) is this person a direct report and do you have any formal management authority over them - as this drastically changes the answer.

You wrote that she is your deputy, and also in charge of your onboarding. Perhaps, these 2 things seem contradictory  ?

@Job_September_2020 - The individual was picking up the responsibility of the role that was filled by the author, I don’t disagree, that could introduce issues especially if the person was selected for the role as an internal promotion.

You will need to be a manager, if you are this person's manager.
At some point this person will cross a line and it will be your duty to say "I have it from here" or "That type of negative comment isn't called for" or other context based statement.
If you are not this person's manager and just their peer, there isn't anything you can do.
If they are your deputy, then we'll assume that you are the manager.
Decorum is a requirement, enforce it.

I would tell her to settle down, and if she doesn't like me in the position to take it up with the company.
I do not tolerate disrespectful speech to me in the workplace.  If you don't stand up for yourself then no one will.

And tell her that you do not tolerate disrespectful speech. First time you invite her to a closed room and tell her face to face. Second time you print it out and ask her to sign it. Do it in HR compatible language. That you want a respectful work environment for everyone.
